# Converting Video using Handbrake for iPad Mini first Gen

Tags: ipad, video, encoding

I have recently received a first gen iPad Mini. My experience with Handbrake is limited. Can anyone recommendation what settings to use on Handbrake to convert HD source ( mostly 1280 x 720 ) to watch on the smaller 1024 x 768 screen without losing more quality than already lost from the smaller resolution, but also without making the files bigger than they have to be. I would also like the video to take up the whole screen without borders ( I don't mind if it stretches a bit ).

Answer (score 1):

As I've got an iPad mini myself I would definately recommend you the **Apple TV** preset.

Your iPad mini does not have retina display, nor does mine (first gen.) and converting to Apple TV format is great (720p instead of 1080p) and results in a smaller size file than iPad preset does.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, the answer is “it depends” because viewing quality is subjective, space is less of an issue on a 64GB iPad than a 16GB iPad, and a desire to use Airplay means you need a higher resolution file.

Your best bet is just to start with the iPad preset and start increasing the Constant Quality/RF factor until you don’t like the quality.